# How to count associated records in rails and display as an integer.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several items, each item also has several sub items. 
I would like to strictly count the number of sub items attached to each item and display that as an integer. Is there a way to do this?

I tried this, but it does not seem to return correctly.

```
<div class="items" id="cell"><%= sub_item.count %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, can you add your objects structure?

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <div>Count: <%= item.subitems.count %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a `@items` instance variable in your view, and for each `item` in `items` you have several `item.subitems`, so you could do something like this:

```
@items.each do |item|
  <div class="items" id="cell">
    <%= item.subitems.count %>
  </div>
  item.subitems.each do |subitem|
    // Do stuff
  end
end
```

Of course i could've assumed wrong.